# Is the length filter required when checking if a field has content or not?

Tags: templating, conditional

When checking if a field has content or not in my templates I usually write something along the lines of:

```
{% if entry.fieldHandle|length %}
    <h1>{{ entry.fieldHandle }}</h1> 
{% endif %}
```

Writing the same code without the `|length` filter does also work, so can I just exclude the use of the filter from my code altogether? Are there any caveats with ***not*** using the filter?

As an aside, I am aware that `|length` does have its uses. You can use this to check the exact value of something, etc etc.

This question was more suited for a simple yes/no check to see if a field has any content and outputting something if it does.

Another example of the `|length` filter in my code would be something like:

```
{% set homepageServices = craft.entries.section('services').type('serviceGroup').level(1) %}
{% if homepageServices|length %}
    <p>Output the services here</p>
{% endif %}
```

Would removing `|length` (which does work at the moment) cause me any headaches down the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably get away with removing `|length` for most conditionals that check for the existence of content in a custom field and just check on `entry.fieldHandle` instead.

One exception to this would be for lightswitch fields, which always return `true` for a `|length` check, but return `true` or `false` when checking on `entry.fieldHandle` depending on whether the lightswitch is `on` or `off`.

StraightUpCraft has a great article on [Testing if something exists](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/testing-if-something-exists-is-defined-length-is-not-null-is-not-empty) and another on [How to check if a variable or value exists using Twig](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-to-check-if-a-variable-or-value-exists-using-twig), which cover a multitude of cases and ways of accessing variables using Twig.